# Encoding problems with htmldoc, and similar programs to htmldoc?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, html

I want to convert some html files into a single pdf file.

1. I used `htmldoc`:

   ```
   htmldoc --webpage --header "/" --footer "" -f all.pdf   0010.html 0099.html
   ```

   The output `all.pdf` doesn't convert some things well. E.g., the
   math expresseion `⌈(1.02 n)⌉` (outlined in red box) isn't show
   properly, and some small icon (outlined in green box) was added. ( See
   the picture  below. )

   There is an option `--charset` for `htmldoc` at http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Misc/htmldoc-1.8.23/htmldoc.html. I don't find `utf-8`. Which one can display math expressions well?

   How shall I use `htmldoc` properly to convert and combine the
   html files to a pdf file, to avoid the above problems as much as
   possible?
2. I rule the possibility of the problems coming from the html files,
   by printing a html file to a pdf file in Google Chrome browser. It
   looks fine without the above problems.  ( See
   the picture  below. )

   But I like a command line solution, which preferrably can work like `htmldoc` to structurize the html files into a pdf file with option `--book`.

   Are there  command line programs similar to `htmldoc` for me to try
   to see if they can work without the above problems?

All of my files (html files and generated pdf files) are in [this tar archive](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/html2pdf/test.tar):

```
0010_files 0010.html 0099.html 0099_files  all.pdf 0010.pdf
```

where `all.pdf` is the single pdf file generated by `htmldoc` from the two html file, and `0010.pdf` is the pdf file generated by opening and printing `0010.html` in Google Chrome.

Output of `htmldoc` and my manually added three outlining boxes:

[image]

Output of printing `0010.html` from Google Chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no UTF-8 support for html2doc. Maybe in version 1.9.

Here is another option:

Install `wkhtmltopdf`: Command line utilities to convert html to pdf or image using WebKit.

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

And install `poppler-utils`:

```
sudo apt-get install poppler-utils
```

Go to your html files:

```
cd <your_html_path>
```

and start the conversion for single files with:

```
wkhtmltopdf 0010.html 0010.pdf
wkhtmltopdf 0099.html 0099.pdf
```

or for all files at once:

```
for f in *.html; do wkhtmltopdf "$f" "${f%%.*}.pdf"; done
```

Convert all single pdf files into one:

```
pdfunite *.pdf out.pdf
```

or as script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Convert all html files in the current folder into one pdf
#
for f in *.html; do wkhtmltopdf "$f" "${f%%.*}.pdf"; done
pdfunite *.pdf out.pdf
```

More infos and options for wkhtmltopdf [here](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt).

Comment: Thanks.   `htmldoc --book` can convert and combine structured html files (with headings, ...) into a pdf file with bookmarks (i.e. outlines). I wonder if `wkhtmltopdf` or some other programs can do similar?

Comment: There is an option `--charset` for `htmldoc` at http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Misc/htmldoc-1.8.23/htmldoc.html. I don't find `utf-8`. Which one do you think can display math expressions well?

Comment: No idea. I have it tested with utf-8. Doesn't work.

Comment: I think, nothing of the listed charsets will work  for math expressions.

Comment: Options for wkhtmltopdf http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

Comment: More complete then this will be difficult!  >:)